# chown not working on mounted directory docker after changing nginx location

Tags: linux, docker, shell, nginx, unix

I am facing a very strange issue. It has been a week now since I have been debugging the issue.

So I have the `nginx.conf` as :

```
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {     
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~* ^/server/endpoint$ {
        proxy_pass http://server:5000
    }

}
```

On changing the path to something as below

```
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {     
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~* ^/server/changed/endpoint$ {
        proxy_pass http://server:5000
    }

}
```

This doesn't let `chown` command work on the volume mounted directory which is

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Below is the `dockerfile` to spin up the `nginx` container :

```
FROM nginx:1.19.7-alpine-1

ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ENV USER=user1
ENV GROUP=user1group
ENV UID=100
ENV GID=102
RUN addgroup \
      -S "$GROUP" \
      -g "$GID" && \
    adduser \
      -S "$USER" \
      -G "$GROUP" \
      --uid "$UID"

EXPOSE 80 443
COPY ./build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./scripts/run.sh /run.sh

RUN chown -R "$UID":"$GID" /usr/share/nginx/html 
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
USER user1
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

So here the `chown` command on the mounted directory `/usr/share/nginx/html` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`chown` does not work when mounting to `root (VOLUME /tmp)`. Use a non-root location `(VOLUME /var/tmp)`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I need to mount the directory /usr/share/nginx/html on running the container with host directory.